# Subscript out of range when using Find on a different excel file

Tags: excel, vba

When i try to run this small macro that i created it gives this error "Run-time error '9': Subscript out of range"

```
Sub Escala()

ActiveCell.Value = Workbooks("C:\Users\ASUS\Documents\File test.xlsm").Worksheets("2016").Range("A:AJ").Find("Julho")

End Sub
```

Did try to check some other's with a similar error but can´t figured out why.. hope you guys can help.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Find will not work on a closed workbook.  If the workbook is open then use just the workbook's name to reference it in the Workbooks collection.  You should test to see if a cell is found by the Find method before you attempt to reference it.

```
Sub Escala()
    Dim Target As range
    Set Target = Workbooks("File test.xlsm").Worksheets("2016").range("A:AJ").Find("Julho")

    If Not Target Is Nothing Then
        ActiveCell.Value = Target.Value
    End If

End Sub
```

Comment: ahh thanks it work now indeed... What i need to use them if the file is close ?

Comment: humm after google found something but it's a complicated way (i mean i do not understand the code)... leave it please